# Core data predicate for a calendar event app

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, calendar, nspredicate

I'm a novice programmer and I've been struggling for two weeks on this one issue. I'm using JTCalendar from cocoapods. It is designed to return a date under  `- (BOOL)calendarHaveEvent:(JTCalendar *)calendar date:(NSDate *)date
{`

which will appear as a dot on the calendar to show an event. To save my event I use the following code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *savedate;
                 savedate = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AlarmData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                 [savedate setValue:CT forKey:@"alarmDate"];

                 [context save:&error];

                BOOL isSaved = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error];

                 NSLog(@"success!!!!, %@", savedate);
```

and the following to attempt to fetch the date and "return" it:

'

```
- (BOOL)calendarHaveEvent:(JTCalendar *)calendar date:(NSDate *)date
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];





    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *textDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    NSLog(@"Date %@",textDate);

     NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"31-12-1981"];
    NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"31-12-2999"];


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(alarmDate >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AlarmData" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        NSString *alarmDate =  [ NSString  stringWithFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

        for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData) {
            alarmDate = [obj valueForKey:@"alarmDate"];

            return alarmDate;'
```

Sadly the result looks like this, every date seems to be returned with a dot underneath:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw0Kf2Z9-yb8Zm5LWnZUUkRJRzQ/view?usp=sharing

I only want to have my single date returned, been stuck on this for a long time. Thank you!

Comment: When working with NSDateFormatter for anything that's not UI, use a predifined locale. If you don't, system will use the system's which can be a source of bugs. You also may want to check the request error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData) {
            alarmDate = [obj valueForKey:@"alarmDate"];

            return alarmDate;'
```

You always return the alamrDate of the first object, no matter what date you have in your method's parameter. Use your parameter to check the date, then return whether there is an alerm for this date or not.